How to obtain a defect configuration coordinate diagram using first-principles calculation?
To quote Audrius Alkauskas et. al., "[a] very important aspect of
defect physics: the coupling of electronic and atomic structure ... is best described in terms of configuration coordinate diagrams" [1]. A typical such diagram is shown below:

My goal is to draw this type of configuration coordinate diagram. I am using first-principles density functional theory through pseudopotential based code such as Quantum ESPRESSO, VASP, SIESTA, etc. I am wondering about the workflow such as the type of calculations or the parameter to focus on in order to obtain this diagram. How can we obtain such a configuration coordinate diagram?
If this information is of any help, I am interested in an isolated impurity-vacancy defect complex inside a zinc-blende crystal (similar to the NV-center in diamond).
[1] Audrius Alkauskas, Matthew D. McCluskey, Chris G. Van de Walle; Tutorial: Defects in semiconductors—Combining experiment and theory. J. Appl. Phys. 14 May 2016; 119 (18): 181101. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4948245

I think that diagram is done "by hand" just as a reference about the physics behind.
